# dependency-injectory and pytest in combination messing up directory calls

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-injection, pytest, azure-databricks

I'm running the pytest command (python -m pytest) locally from pycharm, and my code is intended (and already works as expected) in a notebook and uses dependency-injector. Within a module I have:

**module1.py**

```
import os
print({os.getcwd()}")

container = initialize('../../config.yaml')
container.config()
```

module1.py is 2 directories lower than the root in the repo. However the Traceback is given after using the pytest command, the print gives the path of my root. Therefore, the `'../../config.yaml'` implies to go 2 directories above the root, which is obviously incorrect.

**containers.py**

```
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    config = providers.Configuration(yaml_files=[default_path])

def initialize(config_path):
    container = Container()
    if config_path:
        container.config.from_yaml(config_path, required=True)
  
    return container
```

The error I receive:

```
myNotebook\containers.py:12: in initialize
    container = Container()
src/dependency_injector/containers.pyx:742: in dependency_injector.containers.DeclarativeContainer.__new__
    ???
src/dependency_injector/containers.pyx:393: in dependency_injector.containers.DynamicContainer.load_config
    ???
    ???
src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx:2312: in dependency_injector.providers.Configuration.from_yaml
    ???
src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx:4951: in dependency_injector.providers.merge_dicts
    ???
E   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can I execute pytest properly without encountering this path confusion?

**EDIT**

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_container():
    return Container()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_initialize():
    test_container = initialize('./myNotebook/tests/test.yaml')
    return test_container
```

I had expected that the test_container and/or test_initalize get called.

When I run pytest, the print statment for `module1.py` is:

```
C:\Projects\my-Notebook
```

and is called using `python -m pytest` and is run from the root dir (i.e. also from `C:\Projects\my-Notebook`)

When I run the notebook the print statment for `module1.py` is:

```
/Workspace/Repos/myAccount/my-Notebook/myNotebook/notebooks
```

I wanted that the correct config file, in htis case the test.ymal gets called. However the pytest command is using the wrong directory.

Comment: You could use `os.chdir()` in tests before importing `module1` as a workaround. However, constructing paths relative to current working directory will always be fragile - better change the logic to smth like `container = initialize(pathlib.Path(__file__, '../../config.yaml'))` which will construct the path relative to `module1.py` and is much less error-prone.

Comment: @hoefling Yes this could work, however I have noticed already that the test.yaml file I wanted to use doesn't always get called, instead my production yaml. In conftest.py I have configured just the test.yaml (only seems to get called in the conftest.py, and not "mocking" the calls in the actual method itself).